# memory increase after completion of scripts

Tags: memory, nohup, matlab

(I am new user of linux). I am running several matlab scripts in parallel using nohup in this form:

```
(cd Documents/dir_001; nohup matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('/home/user/Documents/dir_001/myScript.m')") &
(cd Documents/dir_002; nohup matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('/home/user/Documents/dir_002/myScript.m')") &
(cd Documents/dir_003; nohup matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('/home/user/Documents/dir_003/myScript.m')") &
```

I notice (by using top -u ) that when my scripts finish their routines (I can tell it is  finished by looking at directories, when a directory is empty then a script has completed it job) the memory associated to the scripts start to increase progressively. I have to kill the PID to prevent it to keep growing.

My questions:

- Why does not the memory usage go to minimum value if not zero right after the script finish its routine?
- Why does the memory increase? when running a script it consumes 1% of memory, and after completion it keeps growing to values 1.3%,
  1.5%, 1.9%, 2%, and so on.

How can I fix it? I would like to automatically kill the PID after a script is completed

Comment: How do you measure memory usage? Which number in `top` are you concerned about? Do the `matlab` processes disappear from `top` or to they stick around?

Comment: @MartinKonrad It seems I have to place and exit somewhere at the end of the lines of my post. They are stick around dont disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an `exit` command after the Matlab command you want to execute:

```
(cd Documents/dir_001; nohup matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('/home/user/Documents/dir_001/myScript.m'); exit;") &
```

See [How to call MATLAB script from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33231349/7583635) for details.